# React Draft.js toolbar plugin not showing

Tags: reactjs, plugins, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I've followed the [docs](https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/static-toolbar) on installing the inline and static toolbar plugins, but they seems to be nonexistent.

I'm using the Create React App CLI.

The component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {EditorState} from 'draft-js';
import Editor from 'draft-js-plugins-editor';

import createInlineToolbarPlugin from 'draft-js-inline-toolbar-plugin';
import createToolbarPlugin from 'draft-js-static-toolbar-plugin';

import 'draft-js/dist/Draft.css';
import 'draft-js-inline-toolbar-plugin/lib/plugin.css';
import 'draft-js-static-toolbar-plugin/lib/plugin.css';

const inlineToolbarPlugin = createInlineToolbarPlugin({
 //I read somewhere that this plug-in needs this structure passed to it, 
 //but the example in the docs did not use it, and they are undefined anyway
  // structure: [
  //   BoldButton,
  //   ItalicButton,
  //   UnderlineButton,
  //   CodeButton,
  //   Separator,
  // ],
});

const toolbarPlugin = createToolbarPlugin();

class TextEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Editor 
        editorState={this.state.editorState} 
        onChange={this.onChange}
        plugins={[inlineToolbarPlugin, toolbarPlugin]}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default TextEditor;
```

That component is then passed to another component that just renders the editor and does nothing else.

I must be missing something, or not giving the plugins what they need, I just don't know what. I'm guessing the code I have is insufficient to start adding plugins in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You can define custom buttons to perform the desired operations like below:

```
<Editor 
editorState={this.state.editorState} 
onChange={this.onChange}
plugins={[inlineToolbarPlugin, toolbarPlugin]}
/>
<button onClick={this._onBoldClick.bind(this)}>Bold</button> //add button to make bold
```

And now you can write a code to make bold in `_onBoldClick` method as follows:

```
_onBoldClick() {
    this.onChange(RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(this.state.editorState, 'BOLD'));
}
```

You can take reference from the [docs](https://draftjs.org/docs/quickstart-rich-styling.html#content).

Comment: I'm aware, but I still plan on using other plugins. My aim is to be able to install Draftjs plugins overall

Comment: @Draxy OK. No problem. I added this answer for any users trying to achieve this kind of facility.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the buttons before you can create the toolbar

```
import {
  ItalicButton,
  BoldButton,
  UnderlineButton,
  CodeButton
} from "draft-js-buttons";
```

Also, you need to include the toolbar in your render function

```
const { Toolbar } = inlineToolbarPlugin;

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Editor 
         editorState={this.state.editorState} 
         onChange={this.onChange}
         plugins={[inlineToolbarPlugin, toolbarPlugin]}
       />
       <Toolbar />
    </div>
);
```

Comment: incomplete information shared. using copy paste didn't work.
inlineToolbarPlugin is not defined error. 

Would have been better if you had imported all required things in your example.

Comment: Yes, that would have been helpful although that info was in the question which is probably why I didn't repeat it

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMFt9.png)

in my case i have removed the React.Strict mode from app.

it stops the toolbar properties from wroking.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QRBZ.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).